# Facebook interaction between different apps possible?

Tags: facebook

Is there any possibility to exchange information from one App to another via Facebook? For instance to receive information of whether a certain FB user made a certain interaction with that App? The background for this question is that I want to reward users for their activities, but not only on facebook itself but also on different FB apps. Any ideas? I guess chances are very low.

best regards,
phil

Comment: Sure why not? Native mobile apps can connect to a server(php, c#, java, etc) with a http request and this same server can host the iframe or canvas app or both

Comment: but therefore the two applications need to know each other. I would rather get the app's user information through facebook, because I don't know the App's server at all. I just know that there is some Facebook app, and I want to check if a user made an interaction with it. maybe i got you wrong, but i don't know who i should do this

Comment: You can't do that through facebook, the user app information is stored on private servers, not on facebook servers. If you want to that you have to create some kind of api where applications will register on your server and from time to time would send some info about the users or when requested to.